# What are the dimensions of the Passbook pass images?

Tags: ios6, passbook

What are the correct dimensions of the pass images (such as background.png, logo.png) that can be included in the pkpass packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images dimensions are specified in [Passbook Programming Guide: Pass Design and Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW1) under section *Images Fill Their Allotted Space*

Edit: Passbook has been renamed Wallet. As such, all the programming guides have too! [Wallet Developer Guide: Pass Design and Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html)

Comment: It's worth noting that the choice of barcode affects the strip image dimensions (square barcodes use a narrower strip).  Also the ratio of thumbnail images has to be in the range 2:3 - 3:2 to avoid it being cropped.  From experience, you can significantly reduce the weight of the .pkpass bundle by using the 2x dimensions for the base images and not including any 2x files.  Only the iPhone 3Gs requires standard sized images and it will automatically downsize high resolution images.

Answer (score 25):

I couldn't find this documented anywhere, but after much experimentation here are what I believe the correct dimensions of the images to be. Note that if you only include the @2x retina image, it will be automatically downscaled for regular displays.

### icon

- 29x29
- 58x58 (@2x)
- Appears in the mail app, and in notifications about the pass, but not on the pass itself
- This image is mandatory, the package will not open without it

### logo

- 30x30 to 300x30
- 60x60 to 600x60 (@2x)

### strip

- StoreCard - 310 x 123 or 620 x 246 (@2x)
- EventTicket - 310 x 84 or 620 x 168 (@2x)
- Will be center-cropped if it is too high

### thumbnail

- up to 80x90
- up to 160x180 (@2x)
- will be downscaled if too big, will *not* be upscaled if smaller than the max dimensions. So an 80x80 icon will appear as 80x80.

### background

- 312x398
- 624x796 (@2x)
- This appears blurred behind the pass.
- I'm not 100% sure about these dimensions, its hard to tell because of the blurring, but they seem to work.

### footer

Not sure about this one yet, 200x30 seems to work well.

---

Answer (score 5):

Latest 2015 specs, according to Apple's [Pass Design and Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html):

**logo.png**

- 160 x 50

**icon.png**

See "small icon" in [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html), though that document does not specifically has a row for "small icon". I guess "Settings icon" fits.

**strip.png**

On iPhone 6 and 6 Plus:

- 375 x 98 for event tickets
- 375 x 144 for gift cards and coupons
- 375 x 123 in all other cases

On prior hardware:

- 320 x 84 for event tickets
- 320 x 110 for other pass styles with a square barcode on devices with 3.5 inch screens
- 320 x 123 in all other cases

**background.png**

- 180 x 220

**thumbnail.png**

- 90 x 90

**footer.png**

- 286 x 15

Double all sizes for `@2x` versions, resp. triple for `@3x` versions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what type of Pass type you are creating and the type of bar-code you choose.  [The PassKit wiki](http://code.google.com/p/passkit/wiki/PassImages) provides all the dimensions for all different combinations.